# ServiceStack request parameter or session variable?

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I'm working through a typical line-of-business application using ServiceStack as the REST service layer.   All users that login to this system will be associated with, say, a Company entity. As such, the Company.Id is an essential parameter to my all service methods. If information is needed on every request, it seems most appropriate to store it in the authenticated user's session.

1. Should I add CompanyId to every request dto to make each dto stateless?
2. Similarly, should I refactor my routes from `/user/15` to `/company/1/user/15`?

This is probably more of a general REST question, but was curious if there was a ServiceStack-specific solution/recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user is working on data specific to a company then you will want to consider whether or not to prefix the routes with `/company/{CompanyId}`. As I see this, the decision to do this boils down to some questions about how the user interacts with the company or companies they have association with.

I have created this flow chart to show how I would decide to tackle this scenario.

[image: Flow]

I personally have a situation where users are associated with multiple companies, and opt to have a route where the active company can be changed, then all the requests simply read the active company from the session. This saves me having to validate and verify the company id on each request, I just do it once when they change context. But as shown by the flow chart this is only good if they switch infrequently.

> Should I add CompanyId to every request dto to make each dto stateless?

Remember that `stateless` means having to validate and verify the `CompanyId` on every request.

Another consideration, if the API is public and you want to allow targeting different companies then opt for the `CompanyId` in the route. People using you public API may make mistakes if they forget to set the correct active company before subsequent requests. However if the API is private, you will have handled being able to set the active company context in your application, so everything should be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great analysis. Excellent addition with the flowchart.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on your model. If your user is linked to a *single* company the route could be /company/{id}/user{id} . It's good if you want to list all users of a given company.

See some [RESTful best practices](http://www.restapitutorial.com/media/RESTful_Best_Practices-v1_1.pdf)